# serialize and deserialize of linkedList in java

Tags: java, serialization, linked-list

I serialized an object of user defined linked list class, as every node of that list get a memory location in heap, while deserializing if the memory location is already occupied for a particular node , for example

[image]

if the memory of node 2 i.e. 200 is already occupied then how the node 1 knows about it and how the list deserialize?
Or in java the memory allocation happens in some different way.

Comment: While serialization you will save Object's state some where in file so it doesn't matter where they were located in heap. while de-serialization new Object will be created that might have different location in Heap.

Answer (score 2):

JVM is responsible of object's management in memory. After any `GC` is executed, objects allocated in memory can be moved, so the `LinkedList` doesn't actually points a fixed adress but reference

Java has no [pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#Java), only references to objects (safe references). A reference is similar to a pointer, because it points to a variable, an object, but you cannot view or edit the address memory of this reference (unlike C for example).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you would not have to do any thing about about heap manually in Java.

Serialization should not effect heap unless you have some references to serialized node.

Interms to linked list two nodes don't need to know where other node is in memory.

Hope this answers you question.

Comment: thanks for the reply,  two nodes don't need to know where other node is in memory but the previous node need to know where the next node is otherwise how the linked list get traversed??

Comment: maybe he's saying two nodes in a LinkedList (next, prev) are connected not by memory locations but ID when they are serialized, then you don't actually reference a memory location.